# How do step-up transformers exist?

Tags: transformer

Given that:

```
Power=Current*Voltage
&
Current=Voltage/Resistance
```

And that the total power you get out cannot exceed the total power you put in, Step-up transformers shouldn't exist.

So my powersource releases **9v**, in a circuit of **2 Ohms**, meaning the current has to then be **4.5A** according to the second equation. That gives us a power of **40.5 watts** according to the first equation.

I have a transformer that steps a voltage of 9v up to **400,000v** next to me. And if I was to feed the same 9v into this transformer, then if we were to negate the loss of energy due to heat loss (etc, etc...) we should still get an output of 40.5 watts. If this were to be true; the power 40.5 watts, the voltage 400,000v then the current would be 40.5/400,000=**0.00010125A**. But if we then plug this back into the second equation, the resistance would need to now be 400,000/0.00010125= **3950617283.95 Ohms**.

So "how does the transformer increase the resistance so dramatically", is my question?

Comment: that question is identical to "why do current sources exist", if you think about it.

Comment: Is it? I don't even know what you mean by 'Current sources'...

Comment: also, you *postulate* you want the resistor load to still be 40.5 W; so that's what you defined, so you can't ask us now "why". Because you said so, that's why.

Comment: "if I was to feed the same 9v into this transformer" ... "we should still get an output of 40.5 watts" - No. What makes you think this?

Comment: @brhans Well unless there is a conversion of energy somewhere from electrical to heat (or otherwise), you cannot create nor destroy it!

Marcus muller, prior to inputting the voltage, you could work out the total power in the system: 40.5watts, and so after, given that as said above "energy cannot create nor destroy it", it should still be 40.5.

Comment: Your tiny 9V block battery is not a voltage source, so does not "release 9V" and certainly not 4.5Amps

Comment: That **2 Ohms**, is that what you measured with an Ohm meter ? That is **DC**. Transformers only work on **AC** so there your calculations go wrong already. Forget about Resistance in these transformer calculations because it is largely irrelevant. Focus on voltage, current and power.

Comment: If you "looked" into the transformer's 9V side and "measured the resistance" with the 2ohm resistor connected on the 400kV side, then you'd "measure" a "resistance" of 1.01 nano-ohms. This is what your 9V supply will "see" when connected to the transformer. Do the math from there ... (assuming ideal everything and an AC 9V source because DC batteries don't work with transformers).

Comment: Step-up transformers, also step-down current by the same ratio (1:44444 in your case, assuming 9V a.c.). So a resistance connected across the secondary looks like a smaller resistance to the primary, by a factor of 1/(44444 x 44444), ignoring losses

Comment: Ookay...


........

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this 9V to '400kV' device one of those little sparking brick things you see on eBay for a tenner? Because those have a bunch of electronics inside to drive the transformer and they don't really put out 400kV (easy way to tell is that 400kV would jump nearly half a meter)

Comment: The 'transformer' I have is, yes, I brought it because that is what I needed it for. But this question was based off an AC transformer.

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring the detail that you can't transform the DC output of a battery, you have discovered the fact that *a transformer (appears to) transform the impedance*. (By the square of the turn ratio, as Olin provided. I recall using  speaker transformers salvaged from tube amplifiers as mains transformers, and vice versa.)

*How* is a problematic type of question, what kind of answer do you expect? "By obeying the laws of nature" would be the most correct answer.

You could compare a transformer to a pair of gear wheels: when a very strong man tries to turn the big wheel, a feeble child can stop him by holding on to the small wheel. The small resistance (to turning) provided by the child is transformed by the gears to a big resistance as felt by the big man.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what situation you have in mind with your gear analogy, but I think you have sizes backwards. When you're turning the big wheel you have more lever advantage than when you're turning the small wheel.

Comment: @ThePhoton Pretty sure that would only make sense if the gears were on a common shaft

Answer (score 5):

Several confusions:

Transformers only work on AC.  Connecting a battery to the input of a transformer doesn't do anything useful.  You aren't going to get 400 kV out of a transformer by putting 9 V DC into it, no matter what the transformer ratio is.

The impedance connected to the secondary is seen looking into the primary *divided by the square of the turns ratio*.

If you put 9 V (note: AC) into a transformer and get 400 kV out, then the turns ratio is 44.4 k.  The impedance ratio is that squared, or 1.98 x 10<sup>9</sup>.  To make the transformer appear as 2 Ω at the primary, you have to connect 4 GΩ to the secondary.

Let's do a sanity check on the above values.  (9 V)<sup>2</sup>/(2 Ω) = 40.5 W, as you said.  (400 kV)<sup>2</sup>/(4 GΩ) = 40 W.  Same thing within the roundoff error of these numbers.

No laws of physics were abused during the making of this answer.

Comment: I understand know, cheers! Or at least a lot more now... XD

Comment: That would be 2 billion then.

Comment: @Andy: Doh! Fixed.

Comment: Love the last sentence!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yep! Me too! Sometime I'd like to see that sentence in the end titles of a (non-sci-fi) movie!

Answer (score 2):

Transformers transform impedance as well as voltage and current. With a voltage step-up ratio of 400,000:9, the impedance steps up by this value squared i.e. by 1,975,308,642 times. So 2 ohms becomes 3,950,617,284 ohms.

That's how they work.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the very understandable answer!



...And for not mentioning my AC/DC battery error...

Answer (score 0):

A transformer does not increase the load resistance. The load resistance you put on the secondary transformer is up to you (the circuit designer), it is not a parameter defined by the transformer itself. For exemple, you decided to put a 2 ohms resistor as a load for your 9 V battery.

As you said, the output power can't be higher than the input power. Your calculation are correct, to output 40,5 W with your step up transformer from 9 V to 400 000 V, you need an output resistance of about 4 Mega ohms. If you were to load the secondary with your 2 ohms resistor, you would sure explode the battery and the transformer....

Just a little bit of extra information here. A transformer works only with AC voltage, so there should be an inverter in your circuit. If not, this mean that the "transformer"  is used as an inductance and you are using its property to create an overvoltage condition. You can create an overvoltage by charging the inductor with current and then almost interrupting it will cause the overvoltage.

Comment: Yeah, I was just referring to the "battery" as the thing that gives off the 9v. As much as I **DO** actually posses the 9v battery / 400,000:9 transformer, it was only mentioned to more easily explain.

But how does the transformer produce that 4 Mega Ohm resistance?

Comment: It cannot "produce" a resistance... the only thing I can say is that if you want to load your step up transformer at 40,5 W of output power, you need to plug a 4 Mega ohms resistor between the secondary leads of the transformer. I hope it is clearer...

Comment: You have cleared some of it up, definitely!